# Decoding a URL param

Tags: base64, decode, urldecode

Previously, I was able to find out where my Outbrain traffic was coming from because they included a URL param "*origSrc=1534129*" (which is FoxNews.com) in the referrer like this:

```
http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?key=ba8d39805de79b21e0a2fcffd446bcb9&rdid=821633827&type=RPM_/NA_ch2&in-site=false&idx=0&pc_id=21501924&req_id=5b740ff295227c1753749adc72bbb725&agent=blog_JS_rec&recMode=7&reqType=1&wid=150&adsCats=1708,-1,-1&refPub=296&scp=false&reqIdx=2&fcapElementId=22824&origSrc=1534129&did=714910702&pv_id=78d716e32bec0124bcb424aa2eddaabf&uuid=2c2af39f-d968-4e88-8e88-ab230fcd7b33
```

They recently encoded their URLs and they now look like this (taken from a module on FoxNews):

```
http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?p=feJ7Nr753ZKUyzw%2BkQlkGkqo5h6KSzmqBURelKOHYrNFhpUzeNFwXTxpvZ9lBtLT%2FgisNu6dS9DPr4g73pQz4w9YK0W5LSzfsnlqPupuJb3Mcq4pJ7X9LIlPVyzR4QOTRGDIeznBTsTvVl9vPhOW9QJOZPzmQpAK7Q5yMiMwwXaPwzL78WZrc%2BC0bpWCIRwHsJSjqcMVcK%2FN6d8scrmnCAPlDwQVXudXKBRynneq02%2FD9Uqx%2F5zL501Asq0%2BTukd4UBkYdAS21EOSP7AkBn2dJl1G5HXtdURXZst%2F%2F%2B0TcQkRoZ98%2BO8qxKH87AX0uw5a2svIsbL9AmGnX3%2BlLVuMYZFTZRt0LbUnFUWuXFSkvT0oDfO93yhU5Kfcw%2BgpclDQe7NSaHu2ylLobiHuldabM%2B5DslhvZRSG7a4KZkYj%2BRAerkozmIuzDhbydgWPItX3pFDtt0e0tgwZ7Gen%2FT2lmA0qr1%2BLLs%2FPwx098SSR58%3D&v=2

http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?p=309deACtZtKjR3dLT6Bj9O0z08jGMvbDzb%2Fd8oIFnvZXEP7XkkjGe6ZhdKc0g2SYaXZfed7Xd9%2BGTy4%2B%2F%2BPxhWGXYoj5Acl9Vu7d3UPDnTZyzq9q%2BjzRXMMPnFezyYZ4swDqWJf1lRqOpBJhG%2Fmoge0OSSvdL2TdKpTvkf1Nj05z%2BL%2BthUPKVXZJ5cx%2BpSeUDsi4SfKr1VkY8hd6HWmspnwghK6KDuKwUjtzesbzYmp%2Bh9keRCCKUwciJ6LU2R17Wnj6BVm7onAsV4INFNPI2Q9lOb%2B%2FX4QRvPxlQXiV5anx9%2BEz%2B1rGtDUdN%2Fy9wYn%2FdUggxWvYNeEbkP2c3fBhnOFEbonbMjPKILpuJB6736QDoyoMuA1ajf4ol%2FbcIhr4p0JXnqd3NPgiQY1%2Fr69z5tiNucv5FkU9v0ndUP%2FyN4FLg2dzo2GxednAZemvGtveCwXbIYGaCAEuWRUvleHgjWKBq5oD0c4cXvTrF%2BiYvmg%3D&v=2

http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?p=MYWXGHfkM0sqd18Ui%2BFev3GftAAm1Kb6pMI5j7F0ajSSxG9%2F9iYBjIOsnuqKi9vYijInoR1WxEhljCj8x13h0DIq7tN2dbhbJ9XnZUatWQgEifNWdRSD8ctvH2Y7CLvFnn8jLVovdJLyEVhAgbbOp55WiaEBPfKySR6pMUSPxlViQKLqGvpWRihGnl0STT1dpZqXSdYPixEg69pYB1Ug25u%2BQWrqZh9nI2mQe%2FfClHU6RO8DjiJfBLybujkSCa3aZcB9BeQPgsD6ZF824ymK%2FuyhF7TbR4XUsj7VzM06UjHxwOf4yyG%2FKnRja%2Bn7TOctwZlQJS4NM1Hcd9VEUOjZXVstFrUL6eIxw7nyVSfEkHxOr%2FRZFbbuigxQTei%2BhOExXozKbdfVjZlM8DyQEC0vSOk65NZoZH6sqDdS82Kzq3tCo7StJfv7vJqX9M3jHCizFu8H7IrLZ8%2FI3DhNYDWWY5hv1ECQXjrBdBDJvdQmP8c%3D&v=2

http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?p=6iwOm%2B%2BX4zGj74w0QWgyt4ix6H27RiHYp1gQ4qWa3mx90Q2MqZOZTjjiwepqeJpnA9aSwVgJpr9hB0Cy5CM9bBxCVmS%2FGOLl%2BtEc%2B567MNWivjSXAU2KTbV39EqwhOTfCcQAvqtShB%2BM2GtsUyxT63Wt16Q%2B1pMOH17JscejlYAcOjz%2BIkZDQXsKQi3%2FG%2FBzQDTl1suimn3DA63sE230KwmoZPLrgQuSaQENsq9bmcOFHq%2BOGqMLFg9AUKFeXyObjktfdmvPvBCCXH3zNZcYxMAv%2FHCHNGBEzvDHo58h4%2BG15ME%2FriHgPoVbZAVGzpKGspCwPJ8FKOHCjEw%2BZ7PDL%2BeO%2F3MYpqNH5VWVhYna2Tv0zIHrWpRtFSrxqM%2B73DR7gGOogNF32zayMdqHPbUOR2AAkOaW2gLZIn6Z%2F%2F8yh7ms77fgxdeQr8N0IaLOkxhE93UiK9dP216xOaUc64AKcPm7s2qGlW7b3QyG33CBmzY%3D&v=2
```

Somewhere in those four URLs is a param that identifies the site as FoxNews.com or an origSrc id.

Does anyone know how to find out what the origSrc is in the new URLs?

Comment: As defined by Makyen below, these are like very large identifiers. If you look at session identifiers, they often look that way. Identifiers do not include the data you are looking for. Instead the data is in a database on the server of outbrain.com. The identifier is used to access that data. Keys can be really large to avoid (as here) a way to guess them and arrive on a specific page.

Answer (score 6):

The site *paid.outbrain.com* is getting paid by the number of times that a link is clicked.  It is absolutely in their best interest to make it such that it is not possible to determine what the original source is for the link without actually clicking on it and thus getting the redirect from their servers. If they have done their job correctly, then there should not be a way to determine what the data encoded in the parameters to the URL actually contain and certainly not the original source (without a lot of time effort, money, and much more data collected). They want people to have to click the link, not be able to decode the link and bypass recording the click.

However, we can do some analysis to see what is up.  One thing that would help in doing this type of analysis is to also have links which are known to not contain the desired information.

There are two parameters being passed: `p` and `v`.  `v=2` is identical for each; has a value that appears to contain very limited information, probably just indicating to the server that it is a new style link. It can be ignored.

Given the length of the `p` parameter, it is likely that there is data encoded. An alternate implementation would have been for them to just send an index into data stored on their servers.  This would prevent the person receiving the link from having any information as to what the link might be. However, it does not appear they did that.

The `p` parameters for the links are:

```
feJ7Nr753ZKUyzw%2BkQlkGkqo5h6KSzmqBURelKOHYrNFhpUzeNFwXTxpvZ9lBtLT%2FgisNu6dS9DPr4g73pQz4w9YK0W5LSzfsnlqPupuJb3Mcq4pJ7X9LIlPVyzR4QOTRGDIeznBTsTvVl9vPhOW9QJOZPzmQpAK7Q5yMiMwwXaPwzL78WZrc%2BC0bpWCIRwHsJSjqcMVcK%2FN6d8scrmnCAPlDwQVXudXKBRynneq02%2FD9Uqx%2F5zL501Asq0%2BTukd4UBkYdAS21EOSP7AkBn2dJl1G5HXtdURXZst%2F%2F%2B0TcQkRoZ98%2BO8qxKH87AX0uw5a2svIsbL9AmGnX3%2BlLVuMYZFTZRt0LbUnFUWuXFSkvT0oDfO93yhU5Kfcw%2BgpclDQe7NSaHu2ylLobiHuldabM%2B5DslhvZRSG7a4KZkYj%2BRAerkozmIuzDhbydgWPItX3pFDtt0e0tgwZ7Gen%2FT2lmA0qr1%2BLLs%2FPwx098SSR58%3D
309deACtZtKjR3dLT6Bj9O0z08jGMvbDzb%2Fd8oIFnvZXEP7XkkjGe6ZhdKc0g2SYaXZfed7Xd9%2BGTy4%2B%2F%2BPxhWGXYoj5Acl9Vu7d3UPDnTZyzq9q%2BjzRXMMPnFezyYZ4swDqWJf1lRqOpBJhG%2Fmoge0OSSvdL2TdKpTvkf1Nj05z%2BL%2BthUPKVXZJ5cx%2BpSeUDsi4SfKr1VkY8hd6HWmspnwghK6KDuKwUjtzesbzYmp%2Bh9keRCCKUwciJ6LU2R17Wnj6BVm7onAsV4INFNPI2Q9lOb%2B%2FX4QRvPxlQXiV5anx9%2BEz%2B1rGtDUdN%2Fy9wYn%2FdUggxWvYNeEbkP2c3fBhnOFEbonbMjPKILpuJB6736QDoyoMuA1ajf4ol%2FbcIhr4p0JXnqd3NPgiQY1%2Fr69z5tiNucv5FkU9v0ndUP%2FyN4FLg2dzo2GxednAZemvGtveCwXbIYGaCAEuWRUvleHgjWKBq5oD0c4cXvTrF%2BiYvmg%3D
MYWXGHfkM0sqd18Ui%2BFev3GftAAm1Kb6pMI5j7F0ajSSxG9%2F9iYBjIOsnuqKi9vYijInoR1WxEhljCj8x13h0DIq7tN2dbhbJ9XnZUatWQgEifNWdRSD8ctvH2Y7CLvFnn8jLVovdJLyEVhAgbbOp55WiaEBPfKySR6pMUSPxlViQKLqGvpWRihGnl0STT1dpZqXSdYPixEg69pYB1Ug25u%2BQWrqZh9nI2mQe%2FfClHU6RO8DjiJfBLybujkSCa3aZcB9BeQPgsD6ZF824ymK%2FuyhF7TbR4XUsj7VzM06UjHxwOf4yyG%2FKnRja%2Bn7TOctwZlQJS4NM1Hcd9VEUOjZXVstFrUL6eIxw7nyVSfEkHxOr%2FRZFbbuigxQTei%2BhOExXozKbdfVjZlM8DyQEC0vSOk65NZoZH6sqDdS82Kzq3tCo7StJfv7vJqX9M3jHCizFu8H7IrLZ8%2FI3DhNYDWWY5hv1ECQXjrBdBDJvdQmP8c%3D
6iwOm%2B%2BX4zGj74w0QWgyt4ix6H27RiHYp1gQ4qWa3mx90Q2MqZOZTjjiwepqeJpnA9aSwVgJpr9hB0Cy5CM9bBxCVmS%2FGOLl%2BtEc%2B567MNWivjSXAU2KTbV39EqwhOTfCcQAvqtShB%2BM2GtsUyxT63Wt16Q%2B1pMOH17JscejlYAcOjz%2BIkZDQXsKQi3%2FG%2FBzQDTl1suimn3DA63sE230KwmoZPLrgQuSaQENsq9bmcOFHq%2BOGqMLFg9AUKFeXyObjktfdmvPvBCCXH3zNZcYxMAv%2FHCHNGBEzvDHo58h4%2BG15ME%2FriHgPoVbZAVGzpKGspCwPJ8FKOHCjEw%2BZ7PDL%2BeO%2F3MYpqNH5VWVhYna2Tv0zIHrWpRtFSrxqM%2B73DR7gGOogNF32zayMdqHPbUOR2AAkOaW2gLZIn6Z%2F%2F8yh7ms77fgxdeQr8N0IaLOkxhE93UiK9dP216xOaUc64AKcPm7s2qGlW7b3QyG33CBmzY%3D
```

What jumps out immediately is the `%` characters.  We can hypothesize that the `%` indicates separating a field. For simple analysis, we are then interested in those fields that are identical across the different links, so we count the number of occurrences:

```
  Count  Field
  4      %3D
  4      %2F
  3      %2B
  1      feJ7Nr753ZKUyzw
  1      MYWXGHfkM0sqd18Ui
  1      6iwOm
  1      309deACtZtKjR3dLT6Bj9O0z08jGMvbDzb
  1      %2FyN4FLg2dzo2GxednAZemvGtveCwXbIYGaCAEuWRUvleHgjWKBq5oD0c4cXvTrF
  1      %2Fy9wYn
  1      %2FuyhF7TbR4XUsj7VzM06UjHxwOf4yyG
  1      %2FriHgPoVbZAVGzpKGspCwPJ8FKOHCjEw
  1      %2Fr69z5tiNucv5FkU9v0ndUP
  1      %2Fmoge0OSSvdL2TdKpTvkf1Nj05z
  1      %2FgisNu6dS9DPr4g73pQz4w9YK0W5LSzfsnlqPupuJb3Mcq4pJ7X9LIlPVyzR4QOTRGDIeznBTsTvVl9vPhOW9QJOZPzmQpAK7Q5yMiMwwXaPwzL78WZrc
  1      %2FfClHU6RO8DjiJfBLybujkSCa3aZcB9BeQPgsD6ZF824ymK
  1      %2FdUggxWvYNeEbkP2c3fBhnOFEbonbMjPKILpuJB6736QDoyoMuA1ajf4ol
  1      %2Fd8oIFnvZXEP7XkkjGe6ZhdKc0g2SYaXZfed7Xd9
  1      %2FbcIhr4p0JXnqd3NPgiQY1
  1      %2FX4QRvPxlQXiV5anx9
  1      %2FT2lmA0qr1
  1      %2FRZFbbuigxQTei
  1      %2FPwx098SSR58
  1      %2FN6d8scrmnCAPlDwQVXudXKBRynneq02
  1      %2FKnRja
  1      %2FI3DhNYDWWY5hv1ECQXjrBdBDJvdQmP8c
  1      %2FHCHNGBEzvDHo58h4
  1      %2FGOLl
  1      %2FG
  1      %2FD9Uqx
  1      %2FBzQDTl1suimn3DA63sE230KwmoZPLrgQuSaQENsq9bmcOFHq
  1      %2F9iYBjIOsnuqKi9vYijInoR1WxEhljCj8x13h0DIq7tN2dbhbJ9XnZUatWQgEifNWdRSD8ctvH2Y7CLvFnn8jLVovdJLyEVhAgbbOp55WiaEBPfKySR6pMUSPxlViQKLqGvpWRihGnl0STT1dpZqXSdYPixEg69pYB1Ug25u
  1      %2F8yh7ms77fgxdeQr8N0IaLOkxhE93UiK9dP216xOaUc64AKcPm7s2qGlW7b3QyG33CBmzY
  1      %2F5zL501Asq0
  1      %2F3MYpqNH5VWVhYna2Tv0zIHrWpRtFSrxqM
  1      %2BthUPKVXZJ5cx
  1      %2BtEc
  1      %2BpSeUDsi4SfKr1VkY8hd6HWmspnwghK6KDuKwUjtzesbzYmp
  1      %2Bn7TOctwZlQJS4NM1Hcd9VEUOjZXVstFrUL6eIxw7nyVSfEkHxOr
  1      %2BlLVuMYZFTZRt0LbUnFUWuXFSkvT0oDfO93yhU5Kfcw
  1      %2BkQlkGkqo5h6KSzmqBURelKOHYrNFhpUzeNFwXTxpvZ9lBtLT
  1      %2BjzRXMMPnFezyYZ4swDqWJf1lRqOpBJhG
  1      %2BiYvmg
  1      %2BhOExXozKbdfVjZlM8DyQEC0vSOk65NZoZH6sqDdS82Kzq3tCo7StJfv7vJqX9M3jHCizFu8H7IrLZ8
  1      %2Bh9keRCCKUwciJ6LU2R17Wnj6BVm7onAsV4INFNPI2Q9lOb
  1      %2BgpclDQe7NSaHu2ylLobiHuldabM
  1      %2BeO
  1      %2BZ7PDL
  1      %2BX4zGj74w0QWgyt4ix6H27RiHYp1gQ4qWa3mx90Q2MqZOZTjjiwepqeJpnA9aSwVgJpr9hB0Cy5CM9bBxCVmS
  1      %2BTukd4UBkYdAS21EOSP7AkBn2dJl1G5HXtdURXZst
  1      %2BRAerkozmIuzDhbydgWPItX3pFDtt0e0tgwZ7Gen
  1      %2BQWrqZh9nI2mQe
  1      %2BPxhWGXYoj5Acl9Vu7d3UPDnTZyzq9q
  1      %2BOGqMLFg9AUKFeXyObjktfdmvPvBCCXH3zNZcYxMAv
  1      %2BO8qxKH87AX0uw5a2svIsbL9AmGnX3
  1      %2BM2GtsUyxT63Wt16Q
  1      %2BLLs
  1      %2BL
  1      %2BIkZDQXsKQi3
  1      %2BGTy4
  1      %2BG15ME
  1      %2BFev3GftAAm1Kb6pMI5j7F0ajSSxG9
  1      %2BEz
  1      %2BC0bpWCIRwHsJSjqcMVcK
  1      %2B73DR7gGOogNF32zayMdqHPbUOR2AAkOaW2gLZIn6Z
  1      %2B5DslhvZRSG7a4KZkYj
  1      %2B567MNWivjSXAU2KTbV39EqwhOTfCcQAvqtShB
  1      %2B1rGtDUdN
  1      %2B1pMOH17JscejlYAcOjz
  1      %2B0TcQkRoZ98
```

We see that there are no % fields which are duplicated. From this, we can conclude that either the hypothesis that the `%` character was a field separator was wrong, that there were no fields containing duplicate data, or the method for encoding the data does not produce the same output in each URL for any single field that is identical. There are multiple ways for this to be the case. There could easily be a seed value encoded in the string. Such a seed value could just be an index into a list of actual decode keys which exist only on their server.

So, with the assumption that the % marks fields tossed out because it does not demonstrate that there are any repeating fields, we look at it to see what else it might be.

The output above makes it clear that there are only 3 different strings of the format %[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]. We known that for transmitting data through URLs it is required to encode many characters in exactly that format.  Converting the codes used of %2F=`/`, %2B=`+`, and of course the %3D=`=`mentioned in comments. We see:

```
feJ7Nr753ZKUyzw+kQlkGkqo5h6KSzmqBURelKOHYrNFhpUzeNFwXTxpvZ9lBtLT/gisNu6dS9DPr4g73pQz4w9YK0W5LSzfsnlqPupuJb3Mcq4pJ7X9LIlPVyzR4QOTRGDIeznBTsTvVl9vPhOW9QJOZPzmQpAK7Q5yMiMwwXaPwzL78WZrc+C0bpWCIRwHsJSjqcMVcK/N6d8scrmnCAPlDwQVXudXKBRynneq02/D9Uqx/5zL501Asq0+Tukd4UBkYdAS21EOSP7AkBn2dJl1G5HXtdURXZst//+0TcQkRoZ98+O8qxKH87AX0uw5a2svIsbL9AmGnX3+lLVuMYZFTZRt0LbUnFUWuXFSkvT0oDfO93yhU5Kfcw+gpclDQe7NSaHu2ylLobiHuldabM+5DslhvZRSG7a4KZkYj+RAerkozmIuzDhbydgWPItX3pFDtt0e0tgwZ7Gen/T2lmA0qr1+LLs/Pwx098SSR58=
309deACtZtKjR3dLT6Bj9O0z08jGMvbDzb/d8oIFnvZXEP7XkkjGe6ZhdKc0g2SYaXZfed7Xd9+GTy4+/+PxhWGXYoj5Acl9Vu7d3UPDnTZyzq9q+jzRXMMPnFezyYZ4swDqWJf1lRqOpBJhG/moge0OSSvdL2TdKpTvkf1Nj05z+L+thUPKVXZJ5cx+pSeUDsi4SfKr1VkY8hd6HWmspnwghK6KDuKwUjtzesbzYmp+h9keRCCKUwciJ6LU2R17Wnj6BVm7onAsV4INFNPI2Q9lOb+/X4QRvPxlQXiV5anx9+Ez+1rGtDUdN/y9wYn/dUggxWvYNeEbkP2c3fBhnOFEbonbMjPKILpuJB6736QDoyoMuA1ajf4ol/bcIhr4p0JXnqd3NPgiQY1/r69z5tiNucv5FkU9v0ndUP/yN4FLg2dzo2GxednAZemvGtveCwXbIYGaCAEuWRUvleHgjWKBq5oD0c4cXvTrF+iYvmg=
MYWXGHfkM0sqd18Ui+Fev3GftAAm1Kb6pMI5j7F0ajSSxG9/9iYBjIOsnuqKi9vYijInoR1WxEhljCj8x13h0DIq7tN2dbhbJ9XnZUatWQgEifNWdRSD8ctvH2Y7CLvFnn8jLVovdJLyEVhAgbbOp55WiaEBPfKySR6pMUSPxlViQKLqGvpWRihGnl0STT1dpZqXSdYPixEg69pYB1Ug25u+QWrqZh9nI2mQe/fClHU6RO8DjiJfBLybujkSCa3aZcB9BeQPgsD6ZF824ymK/uyhF7TbR4XUsj7VzM06UjHxwOf4yyG/KnRja+n7TOctwZlQJS4NM1Hcd9VEUOjZXVstFrUL6eIxw7nyVSfEkHxOr/RZFbbuigxQTei+hOExXozKbdfVjZlM8DyQEC0vSOk65NZoZH6sqDdS82Kzq3tCo7StJfv7vJqX9M3jHCizFu8H7IrLZ8/I3DhNYDWWY5hv1ECQXjrBdBDJvdQmP8c=
6iwOm++X4zGj74w0QWgyt4ix6H27RiHYp1gQ4qWa3mx90Q2MqZOZTjjiwepqeJpnA9aSwVgJpr9hB0Cy5CM9bBxCVmS/GOLl+tEc+567MNWivjSXAU2KTbV39EqwhOTfCcQAvqtShB+M2GtsUyxT63Wt16Q+1pMOH17JscejlYAcOjz+IkZDQXsKQi3/G/BzQDTl1suimn3DA63sE230KwmoZPLrgQuSaQENsq9bmcOFHq+OGqMLFg9AUKFeXyObjktfdmvPvBCCXH3zNZcYxMAv/HCHNGBEzvDHo58h4+G15ME/riHgPoVbZAVGzpKGspCwPJ8FKOHCjEw+Z7PDL+eO/3MYpqNH5VWVhYna2Tv0zIHrWpRtFSrxqM+73DR7gGOogNF32zayMdqHPbUOR2AAkOaW2gLZIn6Z//8yh7ms77fgxdeQr8N0IaLOkxhE93UiK9dP216xOaUc64AKcPm7s2qGlW7b3QyG33CBmzY=
```

From this we recognize that they may be encoded using base64.  In fact they all decode into 368 bytes of data.  Binary files are commonly separated into fields of fixed length. If the data contained a simple number map indicating that it points to a particular website, we would expect to find an area within all four 368 byte long sequence which is identical across all four.  So, we break out the multi-file data comparator. It produces:

```
0x000 7d df 31 ea         1      multi-diff
0x001 e2 4f 85 2c       O        multi-diff
0x002 7b 5d 97 0e       ]        multi-diff
0x003 36 78 18 9b     6 x        multi-diff
0x004 be 00 77 ef         w      multi-diff
0x005 f9 ad e4 97                multi-diff
0x006 dd 66 33 e3       f 3      multi-diff
0x007 92 d2 4b 31         K 1    multi-diff
0x008 94 a3 2a a3                multi-diff
0x009 cb 47 77 ef       G w      multi-diff
0x00a 3c 77 5f 8c     < w _      multi-diff
0x00b 3e 4b 14 34     > K   4    multi-diff
0x00c 91 4f 8b 41       O   A    multi-diff
0x00d 09 a0 e1 68           h    multi-diff
0x00e 64 63 5e 32     d c ^ 2    multi-diff
0x00f 1a f4 bf b7                multi-diff
0x010 4a ed 71 88     J   q      multi-diff
0x011 a8 33 9f b1       3        multi-diff
0x012 e6 d3 b4 e8                multi-diff
0x013 1e c8 00 7d                multi-diff
0x014 8a c6 26 bb                multi-diff
0x015 4b 32 d4 46     K 2   F    multi-diff
0x016 39 f6 a6 21     9          multi-diff
0x017 aa c3 fa d8                multi-diff
0x018 05 cd a4 a7                multi-diff
0x019 44 bf c2 58     D     X    multi-diff
0x01a 5e dd 39 10     ^   9      multi-diff
0x01b 94 f2 8f e2                multi-diff
0x01c a3 82 b1 a5                multi-diff
0x01d 87 05 74 9a         t      multi-diff
0x01e 62 9e 6a de     b   j      multi-diff
0x01f b3 f6 34 6c         4 l    multi-diff
0x020 45 57 92 7d     E W        multi-diff
0x021 86 10 c4 d1                multi-diff
0x022 95 fe 6f 0d         o      multi-diff
0x023 33 d7 7f 8c     3          multi-diff
0x024 78 92 f6 a9     x          multi-diff
0x025 d1 48 26 93       H        multi-diff
0x026 70 c6 01 99     p          multi-diff
0x027 5d 7b 8c 4e     ]     N    multi-diff
0x028 3c a6 83 38     <     8    multi-diff
0x029 69 61 ac e2     i a        multi-diff
0x02a bd 74 9e c1       t        multi-diff
0x02b 9f a7 ea ea                multi-diff
0x02c 65 34 8a 6a     e 4   j    multi-diff
0x02d 06 83 8b 78           x    multi-diff
0x02e d2 64 db 9a       d        multi-diff
0x02f d3 98 d8 67           g    multi-diff
0x030 fe 69 8a 03       i        multi-diff
0x031 08 76 32 d6       v 2      multi-diff
0x032 ac 5f 27 92       _        multi-diff
0x033 36 79 a1 c1     6 y        multi-diff
0x034 ee de 1d 58           X    multi-diff
0x035 9d d7 56 09         V      multi-diff
0x036 4b 77 c4 a6     K w        multi-diff
0x037 d0 df 48 bf         H      multi-diff
0x038 cf 86 65 61         e a    multi-diff
0x039 af 4f 8c 07       O        multi-diff
0x03a 88 2e 28 40           @    multi-diff
0x03b 3b 3e fc b2     ; >        multi-diff
0x03c de ff c7 e4                multi-diff
0x03d 94 e3 5d 23         ]      multi-diff
0x03e 33 f1 e1 3d     3     =    multi-diff
0x03f e3 85 d0 6c           l    multi-diff
0x040 0f 61 32 1c       a 2      multi-diff
0x041 58 97 2a 42     X     B    multi-diff
0x042 2b 62 ee 56       b   V    multi-diff
0x043 45 88 d3 64     E     d    multi-diff
0x044 b9 f9 76 bf         v      multi-diff
0x045 2d 01 75 18         u      multi-diff
0x046 2c c9 b8 e2                multi-diff
0x047 df 7d 5b e5         [      multi-diff
0x048 b2 56 27 fa       V        multi-diff
0x049 79 ee d5 d1     y          multi-diff
0x04a 6a dd e7 1c     j          multi-diff
0x04b 3e dd 65 fb     >   e      multi-diff
0x04c ea 43 46 9e       C F      multi-diff
0x04d 6e c3 ad bb     n          multi-diff
0x04e 25 9d 59 30         Y 0    multi-diff
0x04f bd 36 08 d5       6        multi-diff
0x050 cc 72 04 a2       r        multi-diff
0x051 72 ce 89 be     r          multi-diff
0x052 ae af f3 34           4    multi-diff
0x053 29 6a 56 97       j V      multi-diff
0x054 27 fa 75 01         u      multi-diff
0x055 b5 3c 14 4d       <   M    multi-diff
0x056 fd d1 83 8a                multi-diff
0x057 2c 5c f1 4d       \   M    multi-diff
0x058 89 c3 cb b5                multi-diff
0x059 4f 0f 6f 77     O   o w    multi-diff
0x05a 57 9c 1f f4     W          multi-diff
0x05b 2c 57 66 4a       W f J    multi-diff
0x05c d1 b3 3b b0         ;      multi-diff
0x05d e1 c9 08 84                multi-diff
0x05e 03 86 bb e4                multi-diff
0x05f 93 78 c5 df       x        multi-diff
0x060 44 b3 9e 09     D          multi-diff
0x061 60 00 7f c4     `          multi-diff
0x062 c8 ea 23 00                multi-diff
0x063 7b 58 2d be       X        multi-diff
0x064 39 97 5a ab     9   Z      multi-diff
0x065 c1 f5 2f 52           R    multi-diff
0x066 4e 95 74 84     N   t      multi-diff
0x067 c4 1a 92 1f                multi-diff
0x068 ef 8e f2 8c                multi-diff
0x069 56 a4 11 d8     V          multi-diff
0x06a 5f 12 58 6b     _   X k    multi-diff
0x06b 6f 61 40 6c     o a @ l    multi-diff
0x06c 3e 1b 81 53     >     S    multi-diff
0x06d 13 f9 b6 2c                multi-diff
0x06e 96 a8 ce 53           S    multi-diff
0x06f f5 81 a7 eb                multi-diff
0x070 02 ed 9e 75           u    multi-diff
0x071 4e 0e 56 ad     N   V      multi-diff
0x072 64 49 89 d7     d I        multi-diff
0x073 fc 2b a1 a4                multi-diff
0x074 e6 dd 01 3e           >    multi-diff
0x075 42 2f 3d d6     B   =      multi-diff
0x076 90 64 f2 93       d        multi-diff
0x077 0a dd b2 0e                multi-diff
0x078 ed 2a 49 1f         I      multi-diff
0x079 0e 94 1e 5e           ^    multi-diff
0x07a 72 ef a9 c9     r          multi-diff
0x07b 32 91 31 b1     2   1      multi-diff
0x07c 23 fd 44 c7         D      multi-diff
0x07d 30 4d 8f a3     0 M        multi-diff
0x07e c1 8f c6 95                multi-diff
0x07f 76 4e 55 80     v N U      multi-diff
0x080 8f 73 62 1c       s b      multi-diff
0x081 c3 f8 40 3a         @ :    multi-diff
0x082 32 bf a2 3c     2     <    multi-diff
0x083 fb ad ea fe                multi-diff
0x084 f1 85 1a 22                multi-diff
0x085 66 43 fa 46     f C   F    multi-diff
0x086 6b ca 56 43     k   V C    multi-diff
0x087 73 55 46 41     s U F A    multi-diff
0x088 e0 76 28 7b       v        multi-diff
0x089 b4 49 46 0a       I F      multi-diff
0x08a 6e e5 9e 42     n     B    multi-diff
0x08b 95 cc 5d 2d         ]      multi-diff
0x08c 82 7e 12 ff                multi-diff
0x08d 21 a5 4d 1b         M      multi-diff
0x08e 1c 27 3d f0         =      multi-diff
0x08f 07 94 5d 73         ] s    multi-diff
0x090 b0 0e a5 40           @    multi-diff
0x091 94 c8 9a 34           4    multi-diff
0x092 a3 b8 97 e5                multi-diff
0x093 a9 49 49 d6       I I      multi-diff
0x094 c3 f2 d6 cb                multi-diff
0x095 15 ab 0f a2                multi-diff
0x096 70 d5 8b 9a     p          multi-diff
0x097 af 59 11 7d       Y        multi-diff
0x098 cd 18 20 c3                multi-diff
0x099 e9 f2 eb 03                multi-diff
0x09a df 17 da ad                multi-diff
0x09b 2c 7a 58 ec       z X      multi-diff
0x09c 72 1d 07 13     r          multi-diff
0x09d b9 69 55 6d       i U m    multi-diff
0x09e a7 ac 20 f4                multi-diff
0x09f 08 a6 db 2b                multi-diff
0x0a0 03 7c 9b 09                multi-diff
0x0a1 e5 20 be a8                multi-diff
0x0a2 0f 84 41 64         A d    multi-diff
0x0a3 04 ae 6a f2         j      multi-diff
0x0a4 15 8a ea eb                multi-diff
0x0a5 5e 0e 66 81     ^   f      multi-diff
0x0a6 e7 e2 1f 0b                multi-diff
0x0a7 57 b0 67 92     W   g      multi-diff
0x0a8 28 52 23 69       R   i    multi-diff
0x0a9 14 3b 69 01       ; i      multi-diff
0x0aa 72 73 90 0d     r s        multi-diff
0x0ab 9e 7a 7b b2       z        multi-diff
0x0ac 77 c6 f7 af     w          multi-diff
0x0ad aa f3 c2 5b           [    multi-diff
0x0ae d3 62 94 99       b        multi-diff
0x0af 6f 6a 75 c3     o j u      multi-diff
0x0b0 c3 7e 3a 85         :      multi-diff
0x0b1 f5 87 44 1e         D      multi-diff
0x0b2 4a d9 ef af     J          multi-diff
0x0b3 b1 1e 03 8e                multi-diff
0x0b4 ff 44 8e 1a       D        multi-diff
0x0b5 9c 20 22 a3                multi-diff
0x0b6 cb 8a 5f 0b         _      multi-diff
0x0b7 e7 53 04 16       S        multi-diff
0x0b8 4d 07 bc 0f     M          multi-diff
0x0b9 40 22 9b 40     @     @    multi-diff
0x0ba b2 27 ba 50           P    multi-diff
0x0bb ad a2 39 a1         9      multi-diff
0x0bc 3e d4 12 5e     >     ^    multi-diff
0x0bd 4e d9 09 5f     N     _    multi-diff
0x0be e9 1d ad 23                multi-diff
0x0bf 1d 7b da 9b                multi-diff
0x0c0 e1 5a 65 8e       Z e      multi-diff
0x0c1 40 78 c0 4b     @ x   K    multi-diff
0x0c2 64 fa 7d 5f     d     _    multi-diff
0x0c3 61 05 05 76     a     v    multi-diff
0x0c4 d0 59 e4 6b       Y   k    multi-diff
0x0c5 12 bb 0f cf                multi-diff
0x0c6 db a2 82 bc                multi-diff
0x0c7 51 70 c0 10     Q p        multi-diff
0x0c8 0e 2c fa 82                multi-diff
0x0c9 48 57 64 5c     H W d \    multi-diff
0x0ca fe 82 5f 7d         _      multi-diff
0x0cb c0 0d 36 f3         6      multi-diff
0x0cc 90 14 e3 35           5    multi-diff
0x0cd 19 d3 29 97                multi-diff
0x0ce f6 c8 8a 18                multi-diff
0x0cf 74 d9 fe c4     t          multi-diff
0x0d0 99 0f ec c0                multi-diff
0x0d1 75 65 a1 2f     u e        multi-diff
0x0d2 1b 39 17 fc       9        multi-diff
0x0d3 91 bf b4 70           p    multi-diff
0x0d4 d7 bf db 87                multi-diff
0x0d5 b5 5f 47 34       _ G 4    multi-diff
0x0d6 d5 84 85 60           `    multi-diff
0x0d7 11 11 d4 44           D    multi-diff
0x0d8 5d bc b2 ce     ]          multi-diff
0x0d9 9b fc 3e f0         >      multi-diff
0x0da 2d 65 d5 c7       e        multi-diff
0x0db ff 41 cc a3       A        multi-diff
0x0dc ff 78 cd 9f       x        multi-diff
0x0dd b4 95 3a 21         :      multi-diff
0x0de 4d e5 52 e3     M   R      multi-diff
0x0df c4 a9 31 e1         1      multi-diff
0x0e0 24 f1 f1 b5                multi-diff
0x0e1 46 f7 c0 e4     F          multi-diff
0x0e2 86 e1 e7 c1                multi-diff
0x0e3 7d 33 f8 3f       3   ?    multi-diff
0x0e4 f3 fb cb ae                multi-diff
0x0e5 e3 5a 21 21       Z        multi-diff
0x0e6 bc c6 bf e0                multi-diff
0x0e7 ab b4 2a 3e           >    multi-diff
0x0e8 12 35 74 85       5 t      multi-diff
0x0e9 87 1d 63 5b         c [    multi-diff
0x0ea f3 37 6b 64       7 k d    multi-diff
0x0eb b0 fc e9 05                multi-diff
0x0ec 17 bd fb 46           F    multi-diff
0x0ed d2 c1 4c ce         L      multi-diff
0x0ee ec 89 e7 92                multi-diff
0x0ef 39 ff 2d 86     9          multi-diff
0x0f0 6b 75 c1 b2     k u        multi-diff
0x0f1 6b 48 99 90     k H        multi-diff
0x0f2 2f 20 50 b0         P      multi-diff
0x0f3 22 c5 25 3c           <    multi-diff
0x0f4 c6 6b 2e 9f       k        multi-diff
0x0f5 cb d8 0d 05                multi-diff
0x0f6 f4 35 33 28       5 3      multi-diff
0x0f7 09 e1 51 e1         Q      multi-diff
0x0f8 86 1b dc c2                multi-diff
0x0f9 9d 90 77 8c         w      multi-diff
0x0fa 7d fd d5 4c           L    multi-diff
0x0fb fe 9c 44 3e         D >    multi-diff
0x0fc 94 dd 50 67         P g    multi-diff
0x0fd b5 f0 e8 b3                multi-diff
0x0fe 6e 61 d9 c3     n a        multi-diff
0x0ff 31 9c 5d 2f     1   ]      multi-diff
0x100 86 e1 5b e7         [      multi-diff
0x101 45 44 2d 8e     E D        multi-diff
0x102 4d 6e 16 ff     M n        multi-diff
0x103 94 89 b5 73           s    multi-diff
0x104 6d db 0b 18     m          multi-diff
0x105 d0 32 e9 a6       2        multi-diff
0x106 b6 33 e2 a3       3        multi-diff
0x107 d4 ca 31 47         1 G    multi-diff
0x108 9c 20 c3 e5                multi-diff
0x109 55 ba b9 55     U     U    multi-diff
0x10a 16 6e f2 95       n        multi-diff
0x10b b9 24 55 85         U      multi-diff
0x10c 71 1e 27 89     q          multi-diff
0x10d 52 bb c4 da     R          multi-diff
0x10e 92 df 90 d9                multi-diff
0x10f f4 a4 7c 3b           ;    multi-diff
0x110 f4 03 4e f4         N      multi-diff
0x111 a0 a3 af cc                multi-diff
0x112 37 2a f4 81     7          multi-diff
0x113 ce 0c 59 eb         Y      multi-diff
0x114 f7 b8 15 5a           Z    multi-diff
0x115 7c 0d b6 94                multi-diff
0x116 a1 5a ee 6d       Z   m    multi-diff
0x117 53 8d 8a 15     S          multi-diff
0x118 92 fe 0c 2a                multi-diff
0x119 9f 28 50 f1         P      multi-diff
0x11a 73 97 4d a8     s   M      multi-diff
0x11b 0f f6 e8 cf                multi-diff
0x11c a0 dc be bb                multi-diff
0x11d a5 22 84 dc                multi-diff
0x11e c9 1a e1 34           4    multi-diff
0x11f 43 f8 31 7b     C   1      multi-diff
0x120 41 a7 5e 80     A   ^      multi-diff
0x121 ee 42 8c 63       B   c    multi-diff
0x122 cd 57 ca a8       W        multi-diff
0x123 49 9e 6d 80     I   m      multi-diff
0x124 a1 a7 d7 d1                multi-diff
0x125 ee 77 d5 77       w   w    multi-diff
0x126 db 34 8d db       4        multi-diff
0x127 29 f8 99 36           6    multi-diff
0x128 4b 22 4c b2     K   L      multi-diff
0x129 a1 41 f0 31       A   1    multi-diff
0x12a b8 8d 3c da         <      multi-diff
0x12b 87 7f 90 87                multi-diff
0x12c ba af 10 3d           =    multi-diff
0x12d 57 af 2d b5     W          multi-diff
0x12e 5a 73 2f 0e     Z s        multi-diff
0x12f 6c e6 48 47     l   H G    multi-diff
0x130 cf d8 e9 60           `    multi-diff
0x131 b9 8d 3a 00         :      multi-diff
0x132 0e b9 e4 90                multi-diff
0x133 c9 cb d6 e6                multi-diff
0x134 61 f9 68 96     a   h      multi-diff
0x135 bd 16 64 da         d      multi-diff
0x136 94 45 7e 02       E        multi-diff
0x137 52 3d ac d9     R =        multi-diff
0x138 1b bf a8 22                multi-diff
0x139 b6 49 37 7e       I 7      multi-diff
0x13a b8 dd 52 99         R      multi-diff
0x13b 29 50 f3 ff       P        multi-diff
0x13c 99 ff 62 ff         b      multi-diff
0x13d 18 f2 b3 32           2    multi-diff
0x13e 8f 37 ab 87       7        multi-diff
0x13f e4 81 7b b9                multi-diff
0x140 40 4b 42 ac     @ K B      multi-diff
0x141 7a 83 a3 ef     z          multi-diff
0x142 b9 67 b4 b7       g        multi-diff
0x143 28 73 ad e0       s        multi-diff
0x144 ce a3 25 c5                multi-diff
0x145 62 61 fb d7     b a        multi-diff
0x146 2e b1 fb 90                multi-diff
0x147 cc 79 bc af       y        multi-diff
0x148 38 d9 9a c3     8          multi-diff
0x149 5b c0 97 74     [     t    multi-diff
0x14a c9 65 f4 21       e        multi-diff
0x14b d8 e9 cd a2                multi-diff
0x14c 16 af e3 ce                multi-diff
0x14d 3c 1a 1c 93     <          multi-diff
0x14e 8b db 28 18                multi-diff
0x14f 57 de b3 44     W     D    multi-diff
0x150 de 0b 16 f7                multi-diff
0x151 91 05 ef 75           u    multi-diff
0x152 43 db 07 22     C          multi-diff
0x153 b6 21 ec 2b                multi-diff
0x154 dd 81 8a d7                multi-diff
0x155 1e 9a cb 4f           O    multi-diff
0x156 d2 08 67 db         g      multi-diff
0x157 d8 01 cf 5e           ^    multi-diff
0x158 30 2e c8 b1     0          multi-diff
0x159 67 59 dc 39     g Y   9    multi-diff
0x15a b1 15 38 a5         8      multi-diff
0x15b 9e 2f 4d 1c         M      multi-diff
0x15c 9f 95 60 eb         `      multi-diff
0x15d f4 e1 35 80         5      multi-diff
0x15e f6 e0 96 0a                multi-diff
0x15f 96 8d 63 70         c p    multi-diff
0x160 60 62 98 f9     ` b        multi-diff
0x161 34 81 6f bb     4   o      multi-diff
0x162 aa ab d4 b3                multi-diff
0x163 bd 9a 40 6a         @ j    multi-diff
0x164 7e 03 90 86                multi-diff
0x165 2c d1 5e 95         ^      multi-diff
0x166 bb ce 3a 6e         : n    multi-diff
0x167 3f 1c c1 db     ?          multi-diff
0x168 3f 5e 74 dd     ? ^ t      multi-diff
0x169 0c f4 10 0c                multi-diff
0x16a 74 eb c9 86     t          multi-diff
0x16b f7 17 bd df                multi-diff
0x16c c4 e8 d4 70           p    multi-diff
0x16d 92 98 26 81                multi-diff
0x16e 47 be 3f 9b     G   ?      multi-diff
0x16f 9f 68 c7 36       h   6    multi-diff
```

From this we see that there are no byte positions within the data which match across all four pieces of data, assuming it is base64 encoded, which is likely.  Thus, it appears that the desired information is not encoded in a binary field of fixed length and position.

So basically, we can either conclude that something was missed in a quick and dirty look at this, or assume that they are doing their job correctly and using an encoding that prevents us from decoding without data held on their servers.

Even if data on their servers was required for decoding, it would be possible to determine that information.  However, the techniques for doing so generally require obtaining large quantities of encoded messages so that eventually the data values used for encoding are repeated. From that it could be possible to determine the unknown data needed to decode the messages.

There is quite a bit that I have not covered.  The field of cracking encodings/encryption is vast and huge amounts of money is put into it. What is here is just a *very simple* look at the data.

The point of most encryption is to make it cost more (time, effort, CPU, money) to obtain the raw data than the raw data is worth. It appears that *paid.outbrain.com* has succeeded in using an encoding/encryption that passes that bar.

Comment: The `%XX` is standard URL encoding for the character with ascii code XX. For example, the `%3D` ending to all of the `p` values encode the `=` character (which is otherwise not valid inside a URL parameter). The fact that all `p` values end with `=` in turn is a tell-tale sign that these are Base64 encoded values. An online decoder like (http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) can easily decode them (which confirms the Base64 assumption), but the quest stops here for me - the resulting binary array does not tell me anything (and does not contain the origSrc we are after :)

Comment: @xpa1492: Yeah, you're right. I should have shown some analysis of the data as base64 decoded raw bytes. I have added the decodings and comparison between the four sets.